# Binary Tree and Linked List, Retaining the head node in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have created a binary tree of a number of different businesses. Each node on the tree is a separate, unique business. Each of these business may have multiple locations. These locations are stored in a simple, singly linked list.

My trouble comes when trying to add an additional location node to the linked list. 
I pass append location the top root of the binary tree, I want to return the top root to my main function, except with a new location node added. When a business is confirmed to be matching I run these functions. I need append to return the binary tree, modified to have another location node, on one of the binary nodes.

```
BusinessNode *appendLocation(char * name, BusinessNode * root, FILE * LocPtr){

    BusinessNode * temp  = root;
    LocationNode * newLoc = NULL;
    newLoc = create_LocationNode(LocPtr);
    temp = tree_search_name(name, root); //will return location where matching biz is found
    temp->head = addLoc(root->head,newLoc);
    printf("temp->head->next->LocPtr %ld", temp->head->next->LocPtr);
```

*SEGFAULT the next location doesnt get added*

```
    return root; // somehow needs to return the whole modified binary tree
}



LocationNode * addLoc(LocationNode* root, LocationNode * newLoc){

    if(root != NULL){
        root -> next = addLoc(root->next, newLoc);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: `addLoc` is a recursive function that does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify from reading your problem; you're trying to modify an existing business (node) in your BT by appending a new location to the linked list of that business node. I presume then, for each of your business nodes you most likely will have a head pointer to the start of your linked list. And from here, you're able to traverse the list and add a new location node. If this is such the case, then your statement;

`temp->head = addLoc(root->head,newLoc);`

is attempting to pass the head pointer of the `root` node of the BT instead of the `head` pointer of the linked list within that business node. Rather, it should be;

`LocationNode * new_location = addLoc (temp->head, newLoc);`

becase `temp->head` is now the the head pointer of the linked list of the found business node returned from `temp = tree_search_name(name, root);`.

Also, your function;

`LocationNode * addLoc(LocationNode* root, LocationNode * newLoc)`

does not append a new location node to the linked list. It simply recursively traverses the list and returns the last node of the linked list. You need to append the last node of the list with your new location node - `newLoc`.

Hope this helps.